# How to exit a chain of functions?

Tags: function, vim, return

I have a few functions which I invoke by this command:

```
Function DoThisOrThat()
 let mysubs="function1,function3"
 exe 'call SUB_Dispatch("'.mysubs.'")'
 do this or that
Endfunction    

 function! SUB_Dispatch(list_subs)   
     let mysubs = split(a:list_subs, ',') 

     if index(mysubs, "function1") != "-1"   
       exe 'call Sub_Function1()'
     endif
     if index(mysubs, "function2") != "-1"   
       exe 'call Sub_Function2()'
     endif
     if index(mysubs, "function3") != "-1"   
       exe 'call Sub_Function3()'
     endif
etc..
 endfunction
```

In Function1,2 and 3 there are if/else statements like theses:

```
If ....
  do this
else
  return
endif
```

If the `return` command in Sub_Function1 is invoked, it still continues to the other functions.

Is there a command to stop executing vim all commands if there is a `return`?

Comment: Your code could benefit from using _Funcrefs_ instead of doing the association of identifiers to functions via `if..else...` Overall, this abstract example looks overly complicated to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a return value to your sub function, like this:

```
if ...
    do this
    return 1
else
    return 0
endif
```

Then, in the `SUB_Dispatch()` function, you can make a test of the return code, for example, replace the following:

```
if index(mysubs, "function1") != "-1"   
    exe 'call Sub_Function1()'
endif
```

by:

```
if index(mysubs, "function1") != -1
    if Sub_Function1() == 0
        return
    endif
endif
```

or, in a quickier way:

```
if index(mysubs, "function1") != -1 && !Sub_Function1()
    return
endif
```

By the way, it not useful to add the `exe` command in your situation. You can use:

```
call SUB_Dispatch(mysubs)
```

instead of:

```
exe 'call SUB_Dispatch("'.mysubs.'")'
```

---

Actually, you could also perform this kind of things in some cleaner ways, for example:

```
function! DoThisOrThat()
    let mysubs = ['Sub_Function1', 'Sub_Function2']
    call SUB_Dispatch(mysubs)
endf


function! SUB_Dispatch(list_subs)
    for f in a:list_subs
        if !eval(f.'()')
            return
        endif
    endfor
endf
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this `if index(mysubs, "function1") != -1 && !Sub_Function1()` --> unknown function Sub_Function1

Comment: Sub_Function1 is an example name, you have to put the name of the functions you created

Comment: Instead of `eval`, you also have: `if !call(f, [])`. This syntax becomes interesting with variadic functions as we can pass `a:000` this way.

Comment: @LucHermitte: very nice, merci!, didn't know the `call` func

Comment: @yolenoyer, that's what I did :)

Comment: @Reman: It's really hard to understand your new issue in the blind; maybe you could debug it yourself more deeply, and/or post a new question about it with a simplified code embedded.

Comment: `a:000` is a |List| that receives all the parameters passed through the ellipsis. 10 years ago (more?) we were playing with `a:0`, `a:1`, ... to fetch parameters and to build the string to execute -- See how unmaintainable [is was](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/plugin/ui-functions.vim#L84). Now, we have `a:000` and `call()`. For more information, `:h a:000`

Comment: @yolenoyer This is my code: `if index(mysubs, "function1") != "-1" |
           if SUB_Function1() == 0 | return | endif |
        endif` --> it does not find `SUB_Function1()` --> SUB_Function1() exists. Where do you call the function `SUB_Function1()`? (or maybe I did not understand your answer)

Comment: I was talking about a new Question, not a new comment... It's not a right place to help people, after ten comments.. Try to remove the outside `if` block; try `:echo SUB_Function1()`. Then, please ask a new question.

Comment: @yolenoyer, my new question would be the same as this question. I don't understand your answer.

Comment: @Reman, really sorry, can't be more clear. I just tested my answer again, it's working well. Did you try `:echo SUB_Function1()`?

Answer (score 2):

I should throw an exception in the else en place the try catch at the first function. I'm not familiar with the language you noted, but I hope it will give you some leads.